# Image zoom JS (with background image, not img)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wanting to write my own image zoom JS code (similar to http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#inner-zoom) but the issue with this and all the other plugins is that it's relying on img tags whereas I want to use background images to give the same effect.

I have created a jsFiddle of where I am up to but I'm having issues trying to re-create the mouse movement. I thought, when you hover, it could scale the background image (or replace the url src via JS with a larger image) but I can't work out how to follow the edges of the image/container rather than the image follow the pointer.

https://jsfiddle.net/x69tk48s/

```
 $('.inner').mousemove(function(e) {
     $('.each-image .bg').offset({
         left: e.pageX,
         top: e.pageY
     });
 });

 $('.inner').on('mouseleave', function() {
     $('.each-image .bg').css({
         left: 0,
         top: 0
     });
 });
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The math isn't quite right (yet) but here is a rough idea of how you can accomplish it: https://jsfiddle.net/3cebzudv/2/ (start by mousing-in in the top left corner to get the rough idea).

Basically, just scale the background image up on mouseenter and then reposition it with the `backgroundPosition` property on mousemove.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, Brian. I get you. And I guess I'd need to work out what the 'edges' are so it doesn't zoom the image 'off'.

Comment: Right, yep you would need to do some calculations based on where the mouse is within the "container" and compare that with how much image you have to work with. This will be easier if you know the image dimensions in advance, but if not, there are ways to read the image dimensions dynamically (once it has loaded), and then use all that as the basis for your calculations.